# Listing with select2 ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a select box listing with select2 ajax. I can list the data from the server but it is not listed in the selectbox. How can I solve this problem?

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" class="js-data-example-ajax form-control" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    url: "/Contacts/Test1",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        "temp": params,
      };
    },                  
    results: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      debugger;
      var parsed = [];
      try {
        parsed = $.map(data.data, function (item) {
          console.log(item)
          return {
            ID: item.ID,
            ADI: item.ADI
          }
        }).value();

      } catch (e) {

      }
      console.log(parsed);
      return {
        results: parsed
      };
    },
    cache: false
  }
});
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your console? what is the return of your ajax query in the network tab of debugger?

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax  Are you sure the option `results` shouldn't be `processResults`?

Comment: There is no error in console. ajax is listed as an array in the result

Comment: @Taplar  I get an error when using processResults( options.results is not a function)

Answer (score 0):

if you getting the array as ajax response then do iterate the response and add it in the option and finally append it to the select box.
eg html:

```
<select class="test-select"></select>
```

eg: js

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
  var optionData = $("<option>"'+ response[i].id +'"</option>");
  $('.test-select').append(optionData);
}
```

here create the option using jquery and append each option to the select

try it...